# What does snapcraft.yml do?

Tags: snap

I'm trying to understand how Snaps are distributed. I understand packages are described by a [snapcraft.yml](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapcraft-yaml-reference) file. They contain shell commands to download, verify and install the software. My question is where do these commands actually run? On the computer of the person downloading the software or on Snap servers?

When I do `snap download <package-name>` I see a `.assert` and a `.snap` file but no `snapcraft.yml` so it seems the snapcraft might be more of a Snap server thing?

My concern is that if `snapcraft.yml` has SHA-256 hashing and PGP signature verification, does that happen on the user's computer or a server -- which could be compromised.

Comment: This sounds like something that is better asked on the Snapcraft Forums - https://forum.snapcraft.io/

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `snapcraft.yaml` file does not contain shell commands. YAML is not a script; it's a way of organizing information. The file is read by your system's snapd during snap install (and uninstall).
2. The `snapcraft.yaml` file is located at /snap/$SNAP-NAME/$VERSION/snap/snapcraft.yaml. Obviously, the snap must be mounted for the system to read the file.
3. The snap's hashing and signature is not done in the YAML file. It's not a Debian control file.

Comment: Thanks! I should have been more specific. I'm interested in lines 40-55 here (https://git.launchpad.net/~bitcoin-core/bitcoin-core-snap/+git/packaging/tree/snap/snapcraft.yaml). Seems like a bash script telling Snap where to find the executables. Is this right? If so, where does the hash verification in that script happen? On snap's servers, my PC or the developer's PC when they prepare a build for Snap?

Comment: Looks like the software is NOT included within the Snap. The Snap is merely an installer of the third-party software.  Snapd on your system reads the YAML, and downloads/installs the software as described. The hash verifies a safe download onto your system from the bitcorecoin.org server.

Comment: That is scary. So if snap or bitcoincore.org is compromised, the user gets whatever?

Comment: Oh-no-malware-could-be-everywhere is a common reaction to folks who are starting to learn about security. Good security is a set of good habits, knowledge, and risk management. So, yes, the user could get whatever. You must prepared for that. Um, you did know that Snaps are sandboxed?

Comment: @user535733 Thanks that's what I was wondering